# why I can´t cast interface implemented in a class in Java

Tags: java

I have a `vertex interface` that contains an `element`

```
public interface Vertex<V> {
    public V element()throws InvalidEdgeException;
}
```

the `implementation` of the `interface vertices` in the `class MyVertices`

```
public class MyVertex<V,E> implements Vertex<V> {

    private V elem;
    private Graph<V, E> myGraph;

    public MyVertex(V elem) {
        this.elem = elem;
        this.myGraph = new GraphLinked<>();
    }

    @Override
    public V element() throws InvalidVertexException {
        if (elem == null) {
            throw new InvalidVertexException("vertex null");
        }
        return elem;
    }

    private MyVertex checkVertex(Vertex<V> p) throws InvalidVertexException {
        if (p == null) {
            throw new InvalidVertexException("checkVertex = NULL");
        }
        try {
            return (MyVertex) p;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new InvalidVertexException("WRONG vertex");
        }
    }
}
```

my doubt is when I try to test the method `checkVertex(Vertex<V> p)` returns `throw new InvalidVertexException("WRONG vertex")` is beacuse cannot be `cast` to `MyVertex`

```
public void teste() {
    //loop to get all vertices form graph
    for (Vertex<V> v : myGraph.vertices()) {
        System.out.println(v.element());
        //I tried to cast the vertex get from graph in myVertex
        //but gave error that vertex not cast to myVertex
        MyVertex myVertex1 = checkVertex(v);
        System.out.println(myVertex1.elem);
        //is the same 
        MyVertex myVertex2 = (MyVertex)v;
        System.out.println(myVertex2.elem);
    }
}
```

making the implementation of the interface, certainly should have done a casting, since it implements its interface

any suggestion?

Comment: how can anything return `throw new InvalidVertexException("WRONG vertex")`?

Comment: if vertex is null or not cast, return "wrong vertex"

Comment: What happened to all the type parameters, why is everything raw? Even if it compiles, it probably does so with thousand warnings, which are there for no good reason. And why do you keep checking that something is not null, instead of establishing in the constructor that the constructed instance is valid?

Comment: Also you should try to post a [mcve]

Comment: A good practice will be to keep the original Exception (I.e: cause), passing it to your custom Exception into the constructor. That way you could easily get the original message.

Answer (score 1):

Remove that dummy `try-catch ClassCastException` and you will know the reason why casting fails.

Comment: Yes.  The exception message for the ClassCastException (which the OP code discards!) will tell you what the actual class of `v` is.